# ¿Por qué "ser la última palabra del credo" es "ser lo menos importante"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, locuciones

Leyendo algunas definiciones para contestar alguna pregunta de por aquí, di con una locución que desconocía:

> [**palabra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RUl938s)
>   *Del lat. parabŏla 'comparación', en lat. tardío 'proverbio', 'parábola', y este del gr. παραβολή parabolḗ.*
>   **ser la última palabra del credo**
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Ser lo menos importante.

Si no me equivoco, la última palabra del [credo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BDesEpw) es *amén*. Mi formación religiosa es poco extensa, pero me sorprende que tal palabra se considere como una palabra cualquiera y no creo que sea un elemento menor dentro de la oración.

Para añadir intensidad a mi asombro, hay dos otras locuciones de *palabra* que mencionan *último*. En ambos casos, para dar pie a un concepto que sobresale como definitivo.

> **última palabra**
>   1. f. Decisión que se da como definitiva e inalterable. *He dicho mi última palabra. ¿Es esta su última palabra?*
>
> **decir alguien la última palabra en un asunto**
>   1. loc. verb. Resolverlo o esclarecerlo de manera definitiva.

Así pues, ¿cómo se llegó al uso de esta expresión? ¿Tiene un uso común? Pues yo nunca la he oído en España.

Comment: A lo mejor no se refiere a la última palabra literalmente sino a la _última palabra_ en el sentido de la palabra más insignificante de todas las que lo componen, es una idea que se me ocurre no tengo datos ni nada.

Comment: Ejemplo en el CORDE: "En tal extremidad, y hallándose como ejército famélico en plaza estrechamente sitiada, discurrió Alejandro pedir socorro a su tía, que era la última palabra del credo en casos tales." (Benito Pérez Galdós, "El doctor Centeno", 1883.)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo unless I mis-read it that seems to have the opposite sense to the definition which Fedorqui found so the mystery deepens.

Comment: @mdewey not really, it can mean that she was the last person you should ask for help.

Comment: He encontrado una cita de Leopoldo Alas *Clarín* que tal vez resulta más clara en el uso de esta expresión: *No me tengo por buen escritor, ni en lenguaje ni en estilo; pero tampoco creo ser la última palabra del credo, en estas cosas.*

Answer (score 3):

El credo constituye una base central de la fe cristiana y es muy importante.

La última palabra del credo es "amén" y quizás sea la menos importante de todo el texto del credo, por lo que, literalmente, "la última palabra del credo" es "la menos importante".

Comment: Para los cristianos "amén" es una palabra muy importante que reafirma toda la oración, en textos cristianos que hablan sobre el credo se refieren a la primera y última palabra como las dos más importantes de toda la oración ya que resumen todo su significado. Yo tampoco había oído nunca antes esta expresión

Answer (score 3):

Otra respuesta especulativa, pero demasiado larga para ponerla como simple comentario.

Probablemente necesitaríamos conocer más sobre la liturgia de hace algunos siglos para entender esta frase hecha, que parece más usada en el pasado. Sin embargo, si en esto es parecida a la actual, según la liturgia de la misa, al final del Credo no se debe decir *Amén*. Sin embargo, muchos fieles, por ignorancia o por costumbre, lo hacen. Por tanto, es habitual oír la oración entera recitada por todos y, al final, un *Amén* bastante más debil dicho solo por unas pocas personas. Esto reforzaría la idea de que la última palabra del Credo (*Amén*) es tan poco importante que ni se dice.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Quiera que no, fui educado en un colegio católico y recuerdo que en alguna ocasión nos dijeron que en realidad en muchas oraciones el "amén" del final no se debía decir, dado que en las oraciones se pide a Dios o a la Virgen que haga algo por nosotros, y no le vas a decir "ea, que así sea".

Comment: Yo no fuí a un colegio religioso pero si fuí educado en el cristianismo por mis padres, iba a misa todos los domingos y a la catequesis hasta los 12 o 13 años. En el credo y en las demás oraciones siempre decíamos amén al final, no recuerdo que se aconsejara nunca lo contrario. Quizá cada orden tenga sus criterios al respecto, no lo sé, en mi pueblo la mayoría son trinitarios. En los textos  que he encontrado por internet el credo siempre termina con "amén" además parece que en hebreo comparte raíz con creer, así se cierra el círculo.

Comment: 1) El Credo de la Misa de Angelis (gregoriano y bastante antiguo) incluye un amén melismático bastante largo. 2) Que yo sepa, la única oración que en la Misa latina excluye el _amén_ es el Padre Nuestro (_por los siglos de los siglos, amén_ es una fórmula que se repite en varias oraciones: colecta, sobre las ofrendas, después de la comunión, y dentro del canon). 3) Una explicación alternativa: He oido llamar _palabras_ a cada una de las componentes de la enumeración (de verdades que se creen): que por algo tiene el orden que tiene y presumiblemente las primeras sean más importantes

Comment: [Aquí](http://media.musicasacra.com/books/latin_missal2002.pdf) está el texto, razonablemente fiel, de la versión _oficial_ de la Misa según el rito _moderno_ (post Conc. Vaticano II), de la que se traduce a los demás idiomas. En las pp. 307 y 308 del pdf se puede ver las dos alternativas del credo (niceno-constantinopolitano y de los apóstoles), ambas con el _Amen_ incluido. Sólo para clarificar, perdón si el tono se presta para una lectura menos amable. (@CarlosAlejo, te notifico, por si te interesa)

Comment: @Rafael gracias. La verdad es que mis recuerdos de aquellas lecciones se pueden haber visto algo trastocados con los años (y mi dejadez con respecto a temas religiosos), que igual he mezclado churras con merinas y, como dices, la exclusión del "amén" sea solo del Padre Nuestro.

Comment: @Rafael, digo lo mismo que Carlos Alejo. Seguramente tienes razón y el *amén* final solo se suprime en el Padrenuestro. Y tu propuesta sobre el significado de *palabra* en este contexto también parece bastante razonable. Similar al que tiene en las *siete palabras* que pronunció Jesucristo en la cruz. ¿Por qué no escribes una respuesta basada en esas ideas?

Comment: @Luigi, pienso que hay que entender el origen de la frase como algo irreverente: son verdades fundamentales, por eso están en el Credo. Pero a un no creyente la vida eterna le puede haber sonado como sólo el final antojadizo de una larga enumeración

Answer (score 2):

En mi opinión puede referirse a la última palabra de un texto largo como es el credo. La mayoría de la gente conoce los primeros versos de la oración, pero mucha menos se la sabe entera.